# How to eliminate NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm new in Xamarin iOS development.
I use NavigationController in my project.
I want to hide a NavigationBar in a particular ViewController.
Following code hides the bar, but doesn't eliminate the space.

```
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        this.NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = null;
        this.NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = true;
        this.NavigationController.ToolbarHidden = true;
    }
```

I want to eliminate the space as shown in the red broken frame.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Set the `NavigationBarHidden` property to false:

```
NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
```

Or if you what to animate that, use the `SetNavigationBarHidden` method:

#### Animate hide:

```
NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, true);
```

#### Animate show:

```
NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(false, true);
```

Re: [iOS NavigationControllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html)